# Why was only part of the Death Star's power used?

Tags: star-wars, death-star, rogue-one

In Rogue One we see

> the Death Star fire in "single reactor" mode at the Scarif to destroy the Imperial archives.

The main question is

> why not just blow it all up? You'd also take out the Rebel fleet, most likely.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can think of a few reasons:

- **They didn't need to.** Single-reactor shots are proven effective at destroying targets the size of the thing they wanted to destroy.
- **They didn't want to wait.** It seems to me like it takes longer to prepare a full blast, but I have not yet had the chance to compare the scenes from A New Hope and Rogue One. Anyway, if true, it was important to destroy the station quickly to prevent further data loss.
- **A full blast was untested.** They hadn't done a full test of the weapon yet, but as I mentioned in my previous point time was of the essence. Better to leave the full test for later, against a peaceful planet with no rebels (or Empire ships) nearby.
- **The Rebel fleet was as close as the Death Star was.** So either they both get blown up or neither of them do.
- **We don't know what's on the rest of the planet.** There may be Empire assets on the other hemisphere that are not compromised. Honestly, I don't see why you'd shield an entire planet for a single building.
- **You can still call it an accident.** They covered up the other test firing as a mining accident. That wouldn't work the second time if the planet was gone.

Answer (score 8):

### The simple answer is that they likely couldn't.

You will recall that the Death Star wasn't fully operational until partway through Episode 4.

> **Princess Leia Organa**: Governor Tarkin, I should have expected to find
>   you holding Vader's leash. I recognized your foul stench when I was
>   brought on board.
>   **Governor Tarkin**: Charming to the last. You don't
>   know how hard I found it, signing the order to terminate your life.
>   **Princess Leia Organa**: I'm surprised that you had the courage to take
>   the responsibility yourself.
>   **Governor Tarkin**: Princess Leia, before
>   your execution, I'd like you to join me for a ceremony that will make
>   this battle station operational. No star system will dare oppose the
>   Emperor now.
>   **Princess Leia Organa**: The more you tighten your grip,
>   Tarkin, the more star systems will slip through your fingers.
>   **Governor Tarkin**: Not after we demonstrate the capabilities of this
>   station. ...
>   **General Tagge**: Until this battle station is fully
>   operational, we are vulnerable. The Rebel Alliance is too well
>   equipped, they're more dangerous than you realize.
>   **Admiral Motti**:
>   Dangerous to your starfleet, Commander; not to this battle station.

However, as Werrf mentioned, the likelihood of destroying oneself when hovering a few thousand miles away from a planet you intend to utterly destroy in an explosion ten times its size... is fairly high.

[image: Alderaan]

Comment: __K2-SO:__ Would you like to know the likelihood of destroying oneself when hovering a few thousand miles away from a planet you intend to utterly destroy in an explosion ten times its size?... It's high...It's very high.

Answer (score 3):

If you recall, there was a fair amount of hand-wringing over its initial use; they had to come up with a cover story for the

> destroyed Holy city on Jedha,

because they weren't ready for the rest of the empire to know about it yet.

Answer (score 1):

You would also likely take out the Death Star, and the *Devastator*. You don't drop a strategic nuke in the middle of your own fleet if you can avoid it.

Comment: The Devastator doesn't arrive until some time afterwards tho. The star destroyers in orbit also appeared lost. The archives were also a direct target. Collateral damage was high either way